# jquery resizable - is there any chance to get whether div is getting resized bigger or smaller than current size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

with jquery 'resizable' i want to resize a div. This .outerDiv has one more .innerDiv.

what i want to achieve is: when user resizes outer div, i want to calculate height of the inner div (i can not give 100% height to inner div).

i am able to get new height like this:

```
resize: function( event, ui ) {
            var currentHeight =  $('.table-container').height();
            $('.table-container').height(currentHeight+1);
             }
```

but when i resize the div to smaller size i want to have

```
resize: function( event, ui ) {
            var currentHeight =  $('.table-container').height();
            $('.table-container').height(currentHeight-1);
             }
```

i am not sure, how i can get that condition, that if resized upwards, size should be smaller (height should be - 1), and if downwards, size should be bigger (height should be + 1)

can anybody give some clues, how to go about it..

Answer (score 0):

I believe a function like below would solve your problem. Note the semaphore and the question mark operator:

```
function handleResizeSignum(context) {
    var previousHeight;
    var green = true;
    function refreshPreviousHeight(h) {
        previousHeight = h;
    }
    context.resize(function() {
        if (!green) return;
        green = false;
        refreshPreviousHeight($(this).height($(this).height() + ($(this).height() >= previousHeight) ? 1 : -1).height());
        green = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks @Lajos for answer..

somehow i managed it through 'alsoResize' option. this worked really well in my scenario..

thanks anyways for your time and solution

Comment: @ShrutiJog, you are welcome. Although, if you have found the answer to your question, I would like to kindly ask you to post it to help others having similar problems.

Comment: Can you post your solution through alsoResize. I am looking for this also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me:

```
$('.modal-content-objectProperty').resizable({
    minHeight: 385,
    minWidth: 600,
    maxHeight: 600,
    maxWidth: 1050,
    alsoResize:".modal-content-objectProperty .react-bs-table-container, .modal-content-objectProperty .table-container",
    resize: function( event, ui ) {$('.modal-content-objectProperty').height('auto');}
});
```

Comment: I do not see how this will inform as to whether a div is growing larger or smaller though.